# How can I run localstack in docker-compose with one command on a Mac?

Tags: docker-compose, localstack

Reading the  [docs for localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack)

I don't understand this line:
"(Note that on MacOS you may have to run TMPDIR=/private$TMPDIR docker-compose up if $TMPDIR contains a symbolic link that cannot be mounted by Docker.)
"
Following these instructions works, but I'd like to be able to run my docker-compose with one command, and I now have to run `docker-compose build` then `TMPDIR=/private$TMPDIR docker-compose up`. Any way to combine the commands successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `--build` switch with the `up` command:

```
TMPDIR=/private$TMPDIR docker-compose up --build
```

`--force-recreate` might help too:

```
TMPDIR=/private$TMPDIR docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

You could even combine the two:

```
TMPDIR=/private$TMPDIR docker-compose up --force-recreate --build
```